# NumPy change negitive values to zero AND all values above it in the column

Tags: arrays, numpy, where-clause

How can I reset all values in a column from a negative number to the top to zero in an array?

```
data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, -1], [-1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]])

resetneg_data = np.where(data<0, 0, data)
print(resetnet_data)
```

This gives me:

```
[[1 1 1 2]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

But what I want is:

```
[[0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

That is, zero where negative, and zero everywhere above the negative. But not zero above other zeros. So that if a column drops below zero in a row, all the rows above it reset to zero.

Can I mask the values somehow by finding the specific ranges:

```
mask_end = np.where(data < 0)
print(mask_end)
```

gives:

```
(array([1, 2]), array([3, 0]))
```

maybe... use those values to replace to that row in a column with zeros?

Answer (score 1):

```
# find values that are smaller than 0 from bottom up along with values above negatives
mask = np.minimum.accumulate(data[::-1])[::-1] < 0

# set value at mask positions as 0
data[mask] = 0

data
#[[0 1 1 0]
# [0 1 0 0]
# [0 0 1 0]
# [1 1 1 1]]
```